# Laravel 5.8 missing protocol of URL when response json?

Tags: json, laravel

I'm using laravel v5.8, and response to JSON with nested object. This nested object has value full url, but result has been remove protocol (http/s).

```
return response()->json(["url" => "http://example.com"]);
```

Expect:

```
{"url":"http://example.com"}
```

Actual:

```
{"url":"\/\/example.com"}
```

Tks

Comment: How are you retrieving/viewing the JSON? I get the expected result when I look at it from the browser.

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: My code: 

public function home_index()
{
    return response()->json(["url" => "https://example.com"]);
}